# R: How to calculate value in computed field column in R

Tags: r, loops, with-statement

I have following dataframe: Dataframe is having more than 1000 rows, I need to update columns P1-P9 using last 3 columns.

```
P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9  Noofmonths  divamount   beginingMonth
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3           29948.333   4
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3           29766.667   4
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3           1778.667    4
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2           2595.6      3
```

Condition:

```
if beginingMonth = 4 then select Noofmonths.
if Noofmonths= 3 then P4 = divamount, P5 = divamount, p6 = divamount

if beginingMonth = 1 then select Noofmonths.    
if Noofmonths= 1 then P1 = divamount

if beginingMonth = 2 then select Noofmonths.    
if Noofmonths= 2 then P2 = divamount, P3 = divamount.
```

Comment: Such a question has been asked (and answered) on SO many times. Search "R dataframe conditional replacement" with the search engine.

Comment: Look into `ifelse` which can be nested. Report back with any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` implementation of your `sql`-esque query:

```
library(data.table)

your_dt = data.table(your_df)

your_dt[beginingMonth == 4 & Noofmonths == 3,
        .(P4=divamount, P5=divamount, P6=divamount)]
```

Comment: Thank you all found way to handle this. Basically there will be 9 update statement i need use. One for each P1 to P9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` or you can use logical indexes, see R-intro.pdf, sections 2.4 and 2.7.

```
inx <- dat$beginingMonth == 4 & dat$Noofmonths == 3
dat$P4[inx] <- dat$P5[inx] <- dat$P6[inx] <- dat$divamount[inx]

inx <- dat$beginingMonth == 1 & dat$Noofmonths == 1
dat$P1[inx] <- dat$divamount[inx]

inx <- dat$beginingMonth == 2 & dat$Noofmonths == 2
dat$P2[inx] <- dat$P3[inx] <- dat$divamount[inx]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in sql. Use the package "sqldf" to write sql queries for the above. Supports generic sql. 
`install.packages("sqldf")`
`sqldf::sqldf("query")`